# We no longer support global installation of Create React App

Tags: installation, create-react-app, global

can anyone explain what is this as far as I know I had installed sanity and nodemon globally they are also not allowed ?

PS C:\Users\Rupesh Gupta\Documents\GitHub\PinShare\pinshare_frontend> npx create-react-app@next --scripts-version=@next --template=cra-template@next ./

You are running `create-react-app` 5.0.0-next.60+6a3315b7, which is behind the latest release (5.0.0).

We no longer support global installation of Create React App.

Please remove any global installs with one of the following commands:

- npm uninstall -g create-react-app
- yarn global remove create-react-app

The latest instructions for creating a new app can be found here:
https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/

PS C:\Users\Rupesh Gupta\Documents\GitHub\PinShare\pinshare_frontend>[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on that project. I solved it by running

```
npx clear-npx-cache
```

and then

```
npx create-react-app@latest ./ --use-npm
```

"./" if you're already in the folder you wanted to CRA into, or "your-project-name" if you're not.

Comment: Genius! This works even you already have uninstalled all `create-react-app` versions